# Do I need browserify if I use ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm creating a new project with ES6 and making a build script.

I'm wondering what's the value of browserify when you have ES6 imports already?

If I point my gulp script to minimize and remove console logs etc. of my "entry" scripts, do I need browserify? (Ie my entry script will use ES6 imports to import whatever children js files are used. In my children JS files, if they use something from another js file, they will import that as well, etc etc)

Comment: You'll need to transpile your ES6, if you convert the import statements to commonjs, then browserify will bundle them for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browserify and Webpack do interact with modules, but not in a syntactic way. The language or runtime provides the `import` or `require` call, depending on whether you use ES6 or Node, but the bundler actually takes those modules and combines them into a single file.

During the process, most bundlers perform some optimizations. Common ones include:

- converting ES6 to older versions (ES5 or even ES3)
- minification/uglification
- including CSS, images, and other non-script data

Comment: `...but the bundler actually takes those modules and combines them into a single file`.. Are you saying that `import` doesn't put them all in one file?

Comment: @Chowza it most certainly does not. `import` will cause the runtime to load and execute the file, then return a reference, but does nothing to combine them. Webpack (and to a lesser extent, Browserify) will look up the imports, combine all the files mentioned, then check for unused code and remove it, optimize everything, and leave you with a single smaller file to serve your users.

Comment: @ssube: the problem is, that none of the browsers supports ES6 modules, resp ES6 import yet. therefore you need bundlers.

Answer (score 0):

> ie my entry script will use ES6 imports to import whatever children js files are used.

There is not any JavaScript environment that supports ES6 modules yet. So you definitely have to convert the files to the module system your target environment uses / supports, and / or bundle them (e.g. with browserify).